# How add/find options of a custom executable programm

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, auto-completion

Let's say I have a simple script in `/usr/local/bin/myscript` like

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    start)
        start something
        ;;
    stop)
        stop something
        ;;
    status)
        status of something
        ;;
    *)
      echo "unknown option $1"
esac
```

**How and where could I provide those three options start/stop/status so a user can display/autocomplete them pressing `TAB`?**

Like e.g. `apt-get` + `2x Tab` gives me

```
autoclean        check            dselect-upgrade  source
autoremove       clean            install          update
build-dep        dist-upgrade     purge            upgrade
changelog        download         remove
```

## EDIT

As sugested by @Ravexina I added a file in `/etc/bash_completion.d/myscript_comp` like

```
_my_script_comp ()
{
  local cur # A pointer named "cur" to current completion word.
  COMPREPLY=() # Array variable storing the possible completions.
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

  # Show it for every possible combination
  # we could do "s*" to only complete words starting with "s"
  case "$cur" in
    # Generate the completion matches and load them into $COMPREPLY array.
    *)  COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W 'start status stop' -- $cur ) );;
  esac

  return 0
}

complete -F _my_script_comp myscript
```

But whn I type `myscript` and press `2x TAB` I now get all files listed in the current directory instead of `start stop status`...

Comment: Brilliant... I have been using Ubuntu for a considerable time now and it never occurred to me `apt-get` has this option. I always used -h.

Comment: @WillemK it's not only apt-get but the whole ubuntu terminal providing the autocompletion and suggestions by pressing `TAB` ;)

Comment: I know, I just never considered to use it with apt-get, cause most of its commands are typed in almost automatically. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file here:

```
/etc/bash_completion.d/
```

name it whatever you want, e.g: `myscript`.

Add these lines into it and save it:

```
_my_script_comp ()
{
  local cur # A pointer named "cur" to current completion word.
  COMPREPLY=() # Array variable storing the possible completions.
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

  # Show it for every possible combination
  # we could do "s*" to only complete words starting with "s"
  case "$cur" in
    # Generate the completion matches and load them into $COMPREPLY array.
    *)  COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W 'start status stop' -- $cur ) );;
  esac

  return 0
}

complete -F _my_script_comp script.sh
```

Now you've got your bash completion for `/usr/local/bin/script.sh`.

My [source](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html).

Comment: Hi thanks so far! Please have a look at my Edit. Unfortunately it is still not working

Comment: You might want to source the file, run `source /etc/bash_completion.d/*`

Comment: I've updated the answer ... check it out again.

Comment: And as @SergiyKolodyazhnyy suggest either source the script or open a new terminal to see if it works or not.

Comment: I applied your changes and did what @SergiyKolodyazhnyy said but it is still not working. Even after a reboot

Comment: is your script in `/usr/bin/local/` executable? cause it's working for me ...

Comment: Oh yes it is! I had a little typo in the last line in my script name! Now it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry now I have a new problem: It only works while I am root (`sudo -i`) as a normal user I still only get the files... do I need some additional read permissions?

Comment: Make sure `/usr/local/bin/script.sh` is available to your regular user for execution ... it should work then.

Comment: Thanks everything fine now! I just needed a reboot (source didn't do the trick).